# How to display all nested relations in a eloquent model referencing itself in many to many?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relation in Partners model that is referencing itself. The pivot table `partner_owners` has `owner_id, owned_id, percent`

So a partner can own another partner and so on.

How can I query all the nested relations for a partner without knowing how many levels are there?

For example `$partner = Partner::where('id', 1)->get();` if this partner is owned by two others and each of the two others are owned by some others and so on I can't figure out a way to display them all without knowing how many levels are there.

```
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Partners extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Owners of the partner.
         */
        public function Owners()
        {
             return $this->belongsToMany(Partner::class, 'partner_owners', 'owned_id', 'owner_id')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new method called `allOwners` or as you wish. In it you must add the following.

```
/**
 * All owners that belong to the partner.
 */
public function allOwners()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Partner::class, 'partner_owners', 'owned_id', 'owner_id')->with('Owners')
}
```

So, if you call `Partner::with(‘Owners’)`, it will get you one level of “children”, but `Partner::with(‘allOwners’)` will give you as many levels as it could find.